# SparkException: Chi-square test expect factors

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, chi-squared

I have a dataset containing 42 features and 1 label.
I want to apply the selection method chi square selector of the library spark ML before executing Decision tree for the detection of anomaly but I meet this error during the applciation of chi square selector:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 45, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Chi-square test expect factors
>   (categorical values) but found more than 10000 distinct values in
>   column 11.

Here is my source code:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import ChiSqSelector
selector = ChiSqSelector(numTopFeatures=1, featuresCol="features",outputCol="features2", labelCol="label")
result = selector.fit(dfa1).transform(dfa1)
result.show()
```

Comment: please add result of dfa1.show(1) and dfa1.printSchema() for better understanding your problem, are you sure that your features col is array/vector type?

Comment: @chlebek show(1): +--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|[0.121478,0.0,0.0...|    0|
+--------------------+-----+

Comment: @chlebek printSchea():  |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in error msg your `features` column contains more than 10000 distinct values in vector and looks like they are continous not categorical , ChiSq can handle only 10k categories and you can't increase this value.

```
  /**
   * Max number of categories when indexing labels and features
   */
  private[spark] val maxCategories: Int = 10000
```

In this case you can use `VectorIndexer` with `.setMaxCategories()` parameter < 10k to prepare your data. You can try other methods to prepare data but it will not work until your count of distinct values in vector is > 10k.

Comment: please when i test VectorIndexer i get the same error

Comment: -Other question, my goal is to have the best accuracy with the minimum number of features and I want to test ChiSquare to compare it with other selection methods.
-So, does it make sense to argue and say that other methods are more reliable and more compatible with my dataset than chi-square that does not support features> 10K --------thank you in advance